# Sort in NSArrayController

Tags: objective-c, macos, nsarraycontroller

How could I really sync NSMutableArray with NSArrayController?

I've got class Dialog and NSArrayController in my UI which bind Content Array to `Dialog.messages`. When I add any new items directly in `Dialog.messages` they are also  available in NSArrayController and everything looks good:

```
[Dialog addMessage: someMsgItem];
```

But I also need sort messages and it's works only for `Dialog.messages` and not for NSArrayController:

```
 NSSortDescriptor *sort = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey: @"timestamp" ascending: YES];
 _messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: [_messages sortedArrayUsingDescriptors: @[sort]]];
```

How can I make these changes are also available for my NSArrayController? This is a part of Dialog class implementation:

```
@implementation Dialog
@synthesize messages = _messages; // NSMutableArray

- (void) addMessage:(Message *)msg {
    [self insertObject:msg inMessagesAtIndex:[_messages count]];
}

- (void) removeMessage:(Message *)msg {
    [self removeObjectFromMessagesAtIndex:[self.messages indexOfObject:msg]];
}

- (NSArray *) messages {
    return [_messages copy];
}

- (void) setMessages:(NSArray *)messages {
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"messages"];
    _messages = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:messages];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"messages"];
}

- (void) insertObject:(Message *)msg inMessagesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [_messages insertObject:msg atIndex:index];
}

- (void) removeObjectFromMessagesAtIndex:(NSUInteger)index {
    [_messages removeObjectAtIndex:index];
}
@end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to sort the `_messages` array. Set `sortDescriptors` on the array controller and its `arrangedObjects` will be sorted according to those descriptors. Then, whatever UI (table view?) is bound to the array controller's `arrangedObjects` will automatically pick up the sorted order.

The complication is that when you need to look up the model object corresponding to a UI element (e.g. row in a table view), you need to index into the array controller's `arrangedObjects`, not `_messages`.

If you really want to sort `_messages`:

1. Don't replace it like the code you showed. Mutable arrays can be sorted in place, like `[someMutableArray sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]]`.
2. You have to make sure that KVO change notifications are emitted when you change `_messages` other than by a call to one of the KVO-compliant accessor methods. There are two ways to do this:

   a. Call `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:`. For example:

   ```
    [self willChangeValueForKey:@"messages"];
    [_messages sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
    [self didChangeValueForKey:@"messages"];
   ```

   I don't recommend this option. It's error prone and is sure to generate the least efficient change notification.

   b. Operate on the mutable-array-like proxy returned from `-mutableArrayValueForKey:`. For example:

   ```
   [[self mutableArrayValueForKey:@"messages"] sortUsingDescriptors:@[sort]];
   ```

   There's at least the chance that this will generate more efficient change notifications (with `NSKeyValueChangeKindKey` being `NSKeyValueChangeReplacement`).

As an aside, you **don't** need to call `-willChangeValueForKey:` and `-didChangeValueForKey:` in your `-setMessages:` method and, in fact, you shouldn't. Since that method conforms to the normal naming conventions for the setter of a property called "messages", KVO automatically hooks into it and generates the appropriate change notifications. (If you want it to not do that, you would have to override `+automaticallyNotifiesObserversForKey:` to return false for that key.)

Comment: I use it for NSCollectionView but think it's doesn't matter. Thank you for your advice and it's really was easier than I thought. The sort of NSArrayController instance works perfectly:

    `[nsArrayControllerItem setSortDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"timestamp" ascending:YES]]];`